# Updating state from child component reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to refactor component elegantly so we can easily use the component for same usecase.

I have two component,

1. NewPurchaseOrder (parent comp.)
2. SelectWarehouse (child comp.)

SelectWarehouse component would render the dropdown list of available warehouses in NewPurchaseOrder component.

The parent component has one state `warehouseId` to track selected warehouse, to update the parent components state (warehouseId) from the child component i am doing this,

**Parent Component**

```
<SelectWarehouse
  updateTarget={ ( ghostValue ) => {
    this.setState( {
      warehouseId: ghostValue // updating the state from child comp. value
    }, () => {
      console.log( 'yokygoky', this.state.warehouseId )
    } )
  } }
/>
```

**Child Component**

```
handleChangeWarehouse( e ) {
  this.setState( {
    selectedWarehouse: e.target.value
  }, () => {
    this.props.updateTarget( e.target.value ) // Updating the parent props
  } )
}
```

Now what i am trying to do, is to send only the state name from the parent instead of sending a function and then update that state of parent component from the child component.
It would look something like this,

```
<SelectWarehouse
  updateTarget={ warehouseId }
/>
```

And then update the warehouseId from the child component.

**Is it possible?**

I have tested it by only sending the state with no luck, also its not possible to bind this context with only a simple state.

Comment: Will you only have one `SelectWarehouse` child? Or are you preparing for the ability of having multiple `SelectWarehouse` children, thus you want to dynamically define the state keys?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to your question will be **No**. But why?

What you are asking is very similar to the two-way binding concept which is supported in frameworks like Angular and Vue.js. That means data will flow in and out from the child component to parent component with one binding. React doesn't support this and highly discourage using this approach. It always prefers unidirectional data flow.

So with React, you can send your data from top to bottom of the component tree easily using props. But if you want reverse redirection, from bottom to top, the only option you have is callbacks. You can pass a callback as a prop to your child component and it will invoke the callback with the relevant data when the data is ready. Sometimes, this is hard when we need communication between deeply nested components. So that's where you need to use a state management library like Redux or [React context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) which is discouraged to use if you aren't an experienced developer.

To understand it better I suggest you to read [Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) section from React official docs. They believe this approach make it easy to understand how a program works than magical two-way binding.

> React makes this data flow explicit to make it easy to understand how
>   your program works, but it does require a little more typing than
>   traditional two-way data binding.

Also,

> Though this sounds complex, it's really just a few lines of code. And
>   it's really explicit how your data is flowing throughout the app.

In your case, probably you have to live with it, refactor to a different format which suggested by other answers or use a third party library like [react-binding](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-binding)(I haven't used it, so can't recommend).

Answer (score 0):

State is something that is specific to a component scope and thus you cannot just access and modify the state of one component from another by directly accessing it, You have to call a method of the specific component whose state you want to change.

So, the first method that you have used is a right way to  do it.

Perhaps to make it more cleaner you can have the logic in a separate function and pass that function as a prop

Parent

```
updateTarget = (newValue) => {

    this.setState( {
      warehouseId: newValue // updating the state from child comp. value
    }, () => {
      console.log( 'yokygoky', this.state.warehouseId )
    } )
}
<SelectWarehouse
  updateTarget={ ( ghostValue ) => this.updateTarget(ghostValue) }
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not right to update the state of a parent component directly from the child. The first version of `<SelectWarehouse />` with updateTarget as func is right.

Also, it is not necessary the store the warehouseId in the state in the child component. The warehouseId can be passed as props to the child component.

```
<SelectWarehouse
  updateTarget={( ghostValue ) => {
    this.setState( {
      warehouseId: ghostValue
    })
  }}
  warehouseId={this.state.warehouseId}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to set reset props from the component itself, for more please refer to [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only).

You should call a method to parent and then set State and pass it to child.

Parent

```
updateTarget = (value) => {

   this.setState( {
     warehouseId: value 
   })
}
<SelectWarehouse
 updateTarget= {this.updateTarget }
/>
```

Child

```
handleChangeWarehouse( e ) {
  this.setState( {
    selectedWarehouse: e.target.value
  }, () => {
    this.props.updateTarget( e.target.value )       
  })
}
```